# Waiting for a chart to refresh, selenium Java

Tags: java, testing, refresh, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an appropriate ExpectedConditions method for this situation. I have a chart and I want to check the text in each row after re-sorting the chart. Problem is, when the chart is refreshing, the text still exists, it's just greyed out. So when I click a button to get the chart to be re-sorted, then look for the text that I'm looking for right away, the test fails because the text hasn't changed yet. I can't use visibilityOfElementLocated because the element is still visible when the chart is refreshing, I'm just waiting for the element to change.

Not sure if any of that makes sense!! It is a really difficult issue to explain.

A little background: I'm using Selenium Java and testing using Chrome. Here is my method thus far. It works fine, I just need to figure out how to make the program wait long enough for the chart to refresh WITHOUT using a sleep statement.

Thanks a bunch everyone! I know that wasn't as clear as it could be, but please let me know if you need any clarification.

```
public void Check_for_text_in_column(String text, String row, String column)
{
    By by = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table_Table_table_ktg\"]/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[" + column + "]/div/div/span");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), WAIT_TIME);

    //This is the line that I need to change: 
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));

    if(!element.getText().equals(text))
    {
        fail("\nDid not find text: " + text + "\nFound text: " + element.getText() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: How long is your current `WAIT_TIME` set to?

Comment: WAIT_TIME is currently set to "30" for a 30 second timeout interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
```

with

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(by, text));
```

EDIT:

Your `WAIT_TIME` is the timeout for your wait.

If the expected condition hasn't returned `true` before timing out according to your `WAIT_TIME`, then `element` will be `null`.

So, your check could look something like this:

```
if(element == null)
{
    fail("\nDid not find text: " + text + "\nFound text: " + element.getText() + "\n");
}
```

EDIT:

Perhaps another option could be something like this:

```
public void Check_for_text_in_column(String text, String row, String column)
{
    By by = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table_Table_table_ktg\"]/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[" + column + "]/div/div/span");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), WAIT_TIME);

    // your original find
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));

    // flag to set when text is found, for exiting loop
    boolean hasText = false;

    // counter for # of times to loop, finally timing out
    int tries = 0;

    // until text is found or loop has executed however many times...
    while (hasText == false && tries < 20) {

        // get the element
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));

        // if text is not present, wait 250 millis before trying again
        if(!element.getText().equals(text){
            Thread.sleep(250);
            tries++;
        }
        else{
            // text found, so set flag to exit loop
            hasText = true;
        }   
    }


    if(!element.getText().equals(text))
    {
        fail("\nDid not find text: " + text + "\nFound text: " + element.getText() + "\n");
    }
}
```

I know you said you don't want `sleep` statements, but I assume you meant that you just don't want a single unnecessarily long one. Even `ExpectedConditions` are using `sleep` internally. They `sleep` for a few milliseconds between polling for changes - and that's exactly what this does, just without the `ExpectedCondition` type wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

That would be a good solution if I wasn't CHECKING to make sure the text is there. So if the text that I'm looking for happens to not be there, I want it to fail, not just wait constantly. Is there maybe a way for me to detect a timeout and make the test fail, but move on?

Comment: `WAIT_TIME` is a timeout. Updated my answer to show how to use that.

Comment: I'll give this a shot now. Note that textToBePresentInElement returns a boolean, not an element. I'll try to work with it. Thanks again! Your help is greatly appreciated. I would upvote your answer if I could. I'll accept it if everything works out! :) Cheers!!

Edit - it's also a static method, so I can just call it as is.

Comment: The `ExpectedCondition` is being passed to the `wait` which returns a `WebElement`

Comment: Oh! Duh. Now to figure out why my IDE isn't accepting it. Thanks again!

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work. I'm declaring as such now: 

    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(by, text));

But it's giving me a compilation error about incompatible types.

Comment: com/gfk/starwood/senbot/cucumber/stepdefinitions/StepDefinitions.java:[144,39] error: incompatible types

That's what I'm getting.

Comment: Ok. Which line is on 144 and 39?

Comment: I think something like that can do it! I'll work with it. Thank you again!

Comment: Code `if(element == null) { fail("...\nFound text: " + element.getText() + "\n"); }` is not correct